# Cannot display another ViewController when TableView cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I want to display a new ViewController (storyboard id: `TaskDetailsVC`) when a cell from my TableView is selected. This is my TableView code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    displayTask.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let row = Tasks.sharedInstance.datas[indexPath.row]
    print(row)
    let TaskDetailsVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TaskDetailsVC") as! TaskDetailsViewController
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(TaskDetailsVC, animated: true)
}
```

I can see an arrow on the right hand corner of each row but nothing happens when I click the cell. How can I fix it?

My ViewController code can be found here https://codeshare.io/C4uNh

Comment: Does this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function get called when you tap the cell? Is the table view's delegate set?

Comment: Pin a breakpoint inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function and check out if it was called ?

Comment: Check your present controllers parents class/super class is UINavigationController or not?

Comment: @Phuc It doesn't seem to be called.. Do you know to fix it?

Comment: @Pavan how do I do that?

Comment: @rmaddy no it does not seem to be called. Do you know how I can get it to be called?

Comment: Simply check your IBOutlet connect correctly and delegate and datasource connect correctly via programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following line inside your viewDidLoad method

```
 displayTask.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinnk that your delegate is not set !! right click in storyboard and see that it set or not or may your IBOutlet is not set proparly

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:-

```
displayTask.delegate = self
```

[image: delegate missing]